# Facebook and Twitter data scraping using perl

Tags: perl, facebook-like

I want to create a web dashboard where i can search any user by name from facebook, & twitter and then show all the details (public like educations about , likes ) on my dashboard.

How this can be done using perl?

I cant use graph API as it shows for only users allow my app (permission based.)

Please guide me .

Answer (score 1):

This question is broad. Have a look at below CPAN modules, write your logic on top of it. If you face any problem show us where you get stuck with a minimal example.

- [Facebook::Graph](https://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::Graph)
- [API::Facebook](https://metacpan.org/pod/API::Facebook)

Check more at: https://metacpan.org/search?q=Facebook&search_type=modules

- [Net::Twitter](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Twitter/lib/Net/Twitter.pod)
- [API::Twitter](https://metacpan.org/pod/API::Twitter)

Check more at: https://metacpan.org/search?q=Twitter&search_type=modules

---

> I cant use graph API as it shows for only users allow my app

There's a reason for it, right?